# extract infopath xml data into excel

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-list

Hi I have a sharepoint library, in which first column is a InfoPath xml column. There are around 2000 xmls in the list. I want to export the data from InfoPath in excel, but using "Export to excel" I am getting all columns of library in excel with first column data as InfoPath path

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 does not have a column type of "InfoPath xml column". SharePoint libraries have files. The contents of InfoPath forms are stored as xml files within a SharePoint form library. You're asking for a way to open all files in a SharePoint library as text files, then take their contents and paste them into an Excel column? That functionality is definitely supported out of the box. Depending on your skillset, you could make [an Excel macro](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html), create [form code to export the xml through InfoPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa945227.aspx), or [use PowerShell to scrape the data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2012/02/13/10265370.aspx).